# how do you traverse a json file using go-simplejson

Tags: json, go, simplejson

I have a JSON file of the form:

```
{
  "data": {
    "docs": [
      {"key00": "val00", "key01": "val01"},
      {"key10": "val10", "key11": "val11"}
    ]
  }
}
```

and I would like to convert it to separate JSON docs:

### file0.json

```
{
  {"key00": "val00", "key01": "val01"}
}
```

### file1.json

```
{
   {"key10": "val10", "key11": "val11"}
}
```

I can enumerate over the array contents using:

```
j, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
dec, _ := simplejson.NewFromReader(bytes.NewReader(j))
for i,v := range dec.Get("data").Get("docs").MustArray() {
  out := simplejson.New()

  /* ??? move dec key/value pairs to out ??? */

  b, _ := out.EncodePretty()
  ioutil.WriteFile(outpath, b, 0777)
}
```

but I'm not sure how to iterate over the key/value pairs within the array entries. It's a nice, succinct library but there don't appear to be a lot of examples and my golang expertise is currently limited.

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`simplejson.Set`](https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson/blob/master/simplejson.go#L56):

```
for _, doc := range dec.Get("data").Get("docs").MustArray() {
    out := simplejson.New()
    // doc is an interface{} holding a map, we have to type assert it.
    for k, v := range doc.(map[string]interface{}) {
        out.Set(k, v)
    }
    b, _ := out.EncodePretty()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
}
```

However in that instance, simplejson is an overkill and using a struct / stdlib is more efficient.

For completeness sake, the std lib version:

```
type DataLayout struct {
    Data struct {
        Docs []map[string]string `json:"docs"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    var in DataLayout
    err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(j)).Decode(&in)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, doc := range in.Data.Docs {
        b, err := json.MarshalIndent(doc, "", "\t")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>play</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/-02qd0pFAA)

Notes:

- Your json example is wrong, `"key10", "val10"` should be `"key10": "val10"`.
- When you're in doubt of how a data structure looks and too lazy to read the code, use `fmt.Printf("%#v", doc)` to see how it looks like.

Comment: thanks - the actual document is quite a bit bigger than this simple subset and the simplejson is more succinct so I'm ok with it. I don't usually think of "simple" as overkill, but perhaps "simple" in this case refers to the relatively few lines of code - the need to do a type assert isn't "simple" IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason to use simplejson? A lot of encoding can be done with the [standard JSON library](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

Using the standard library you could solve your problem like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Document struct {
    Data DataStruct
}

type DataStruct struct {
    Docs []interface{}
}

func main() {
    doc, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./doc.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var document Document
    err = json.Unmarshal(doc, &document)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for index := range document.Data.Docs {
        b, err := json.Marshal(document.Data.Docs[index])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        err = ioutil.WriteFile(fmt.Sprintf("file%d.json", index), b, 0777)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b))
    }
}
```

The sample code will provide you two files with contents like this:

```
{"key00":"val00","key01":"val01"}
```

and

```
{"key10":"val10","key11":"val11"}
```

However, if you noticed I used the []interface{} notation in the DataStruct, which in general is considered bad practice. You should create a new structure with proper type declarations if your real-world data has any.

Comment: thanks Juuso. That would work just fine. I think i have to give preference to OneOfOne for succinctness, though. BTW there is a benchmark out there which shows that the Python version of simplejson was 5x faster than encoding/json (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/zCBUEB_MfVs) though it seemed to be controversial. I don't know enough at this point to attempt a meaningful benchmark myself.

Comment: @JamesFremen Ah, I probably wouldn't have recommended you to use the standard library should I have known you are dealing with huge files. I recall it having some performance issues. Anyhow, I'm not familiar with simplejson, but I'm glad you found somebody who was.

Comment: It looks like go-simplejson just wraps the standard library anyway.

Comment: I prefer few extra lines of code over extra dependencies. Go's dependency management is still kind of mess which gives you additional reason to avoid any unneeded ones.